# Creating Temporal table without adding DateTime columns

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I'm an SQL server DBA and new to Temporal tables. We have the following issue:
As part of implementing temporal tables mechanism , there's a need to add to datetime columns (so DWH will have the ability to investigate only last modified columns).

1. 1st problem is that our R&D are trying to avoid from altering table structure (adding columns) as it is a sensitive and big table.
2. 2nd problem is that the original table contains MODIF DATE column.
   This column is being updated at the datetime value of the **update** transaction **beginning** time warriors I need the **COMMIT** time.(gaps are critical)

[image]

**My question**:

Is there a possibility to turn the original table to Temporal one , without adding columns and only by using the CREATION date and MODIF date built-in columns?

Will appreciate any support here!

Comment: The short answer is NO. Also refer to my answer [Do temporal tables log changes when there are none?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/do-temporal-tables-log-changes-when-there-are-none) wherein the loggin behaviour is a bit different - and you will have to maintain / prune the data wisely.

Comment: [Migrate existing tables to built-in support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#migrate-existing-tables-to-built-in-support)

Answer (score -2):

If you're using [**System-Versioned Temporal Tables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/getting-started-with-system-versioned-temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) then I believe you need not change your table schema. Rather separate tables are created to automatically manage history on your existing tables.

There's also alternatives in SQL Server that shouldn't require you to change your existing table schema either such as [**Change Tracking**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or [**Change Data Capture (CDC)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks allot for your quick support. But even in the article you've attached I can see that adding datetime columns on the original table is essential. As for the other alternative's I prefer avoiding from using other solutions now , unless  there will be no bypassing way to the table schema changes.

Comment: @user4443389 I'd be rather surprised if that was a hard requirement of **Temporal Tables** but I haven't looked into them in a while, so it's definitely possible. I'll have to refresh on the documentation I linked because it offers about 5 different ways of using **Temporal Tables** and I'll update my answer accordingly. If it is a requirement, then I think your only alternatives are the ones I linked. **Change Tracking** is probably the simplest and minimalist footprint to implement of the two.

Comment: Thanks , awaiting your updates.